# Autolayout with 3 labels equally width

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I need to display 3 labels like this : "|-15-[Label1]-0-[Label2]-0-[Label3]-15|".The label1,label2,label3 should have equal widths.How could I acthieve this using autolayout with coding.Any suggestion is appreciated.

I've tried the as below,but I couldn't see anything on my headerview.

```
NSDictionary *views2 = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label1, label2, label3);

[headerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-leftPadding-[label1]-0-[label2]-0-[label3]-rightPadding-|" options:0 metrics:@{@"leftPadding":[NSNumber numberWithInt:15],@"rightPadding":[NSNumber numberWithInt:15]} views:views2]];

[headerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label1
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:label2
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      multiplier:1
                                                        constant:0]];

[headerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label1
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:label3
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      multiplier:1
                                                        constant:0]];

[headerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label2
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:label3
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      multiplier:1
                                                        constant:0]];


[headerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[label1]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views2]];
[headerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[label2]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views2]];
[headerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[label3]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views2]];
```

Comment: Your code can be shortened with this format: `@"H:|-leftPadding-[label1]-0-[label2(==label1)]-0-[label3(==label2)]-rightPadding-|"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want some views to have same width irrespective of distance between them. You should use the concept of spacer views. Refer to apple documentation for more information on Spacer views. I think spacer would be the best way to go about this. When you have used spacers you need to apply the constraints to the spacer views which will cause your labels to become equal in width.